Simple indicator, I just suck. How can I access future candles in pine script?
Indicator is very simple but I am not good with programming.
I want to mark daily lows and highs, so I got the condition to plot a horizontal line when there is a green then red candle, or red then green. The line is plotted on the previous Close of those 2 candlesexample
The only problem is that I want to filter out those lines that intersect future candles.
Either not plotting them or limiting their right end to the bar they intersect.
Requirements Recap:
Detect a color change (green to red or red to green).
Draw a horizontal line at the previous day’s close.
Exclude the line if it intersects any future candles’ price range.
Thanks for helping
Since pine goes candle by candle I tried to put all the lines in the array and then access it on every next candle and check if any intersects with a current candle.
//@version=6
indicator('Flip Levels Daily Fixed', overlay = true)

// Helper functions for candle colors
isGreen() =>
    close > open

isRed() =>
    close < open

// Fetch daily high, low, and close regardless of chart timeframe
dailyHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high)
dailyLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low)
dailyClose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)

// Track previous daily candle states
var float prevDailyClose = na
var bool prevDailyRed = false
var bool prevDailyGreen = false

// Conditions for daily candles
dailyRedThenGreen = (dailyClose > open) and prevDailyRed
dailyGreenThenRed = (dailyClose < open) and prevDailyGreen

// Array to store rays
var array<line> rays = array.new<line>()

// Add new rays when conditions are met
if dailyRedThenGreen
    newRay = line.new(x1=bar_index - 1, y1=prevDailyClose, x2=bar_index, y2=prevDailyClose, color=color.red, style=line.style_solid, width=2)
    array.push(rays, newRay)

if dailyGreenThenRed
    newRay = line.new(x1=bar_index - 1, y1=prevDailyClose, x2=bar_index, y2=prevDailyClose, color=color.green, style=line.style_solid, width=2)
    array.push(rays, newRay)

// Update rays and check for intersection
if array.size(rays) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(rays) - 1
        ray = array.get(rays, i)
        rayY1 = line.get_y1(ray)

        // Add a small margin for comparison
        margin = 0.0001

        // Check if the ray intersects the current daily candle's range
        if rayY1 >= dailyLow - margin and rayY1 <= dailyHigh + margin
            // Intersection detected, stop ray at current bar
            line.set_x2(ray, bar_index)
        else
            // No intersection, extend ray further
            line.set_x2(ray, bar_index + 50)

// Update previous daily states
prevDailyClose := dailyClose
prevDailyRed := (dailyClose < open)
prevDailyGreen := (dailyClose > open)

